# How to make non-event javascript instructions work after inserting DOM element?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Event-delegation must be used to make events work after inserting DOM elements (i.e Ajax response) but what about basic JS instructions?

As you will see, all the instructions are sorted by affected PHP page (to update and improve the code more easily, and not to repeat the same instructions several times).
Here, I want to test if a given class exists. This class doesn't exist when the JS file is loaded, but will be after inserting the AJAX response.

Code example

```
// NAVBAR.PHP

if ( $('.className').length) {

$('.button-navbar').show(); }      

 /* FOOTER.PHP
 .... */

// VIEW_NEWS.PHP

$('.ajax_wrapper').on('click', '#view_news tr', function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var get_news_request = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "view_news.php", data: {news_id: id}, dataType: "html"});

    get_news_request.done(function(html) {

        $('.ajax_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, function(){

            $('.ajax_wrapper').empty();
            $('.ajax_wrapper').hide().html(html);
            $('.ajax_wrapper').show('slide');

        });

    });

    get_news_request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown );
    });

});
```

Unfortunately,

```
if ( $('.className').length) {

$('.button-navbar').show(); }
```

doesn't seem to be executed, whereas the class now exists.

Do you have a solution which does not break the JS file architecture ?

Comment: please test this page with your "firefox" console on, and you will find some js errors before the code `if ( $('.className').length) {
$('.button-navbar').show(); } ` is executed.

Comment: I don't see any error, the navbar button appears if I execute this instruction in the console (of course after the Ajax response has been inserted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code isn't an event handler and doesn't set up any sort of permanent rule. It's just straight procedural code, there's no reason it would get called again automatically. At the time it was executed, there was on such class. Adding a class will not make the code execute again.

However, you can manually do that check in both places (at the beginning, and in the ajax callback). To avoid duplication, you can put the shared functionality into an actual function:

```
function show_navbar_check() {
    if ( $('.className').length)
        $('.button-navbar').show();
}

show_navbar_check();
```

And then call it in the ajax callback too:

```
$('.ajax_wrapper').on('click', '#view_news tr', function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var get_news_request = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "view_news.php", data: {news_id: id}, dataType: "html"});

    get_news_request.done(function(html) {

        $('.ajax_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, function(){

            $('.ajax_wrapper').empty();
            $('.ajax_wrapper').hide().html(html);
            $('.ajax_wrapper').show('slide');

            /* I added the line below */
            show_navbar_check();
        });

    });

    get_news_request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown );
    });

});
```

*Sidenote: there is also a solution to this problem using [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), but I didn't include it because I think the above is better, in part for efficiency reasons.*

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I've just read about global ajax event `.ajaxComplete(handler)`, it may be more appropriate in my case.

Comment: @b1onic, be careful about using .ajaxComplete, it can cause unexpected behavior when, for example, you come back to the code in six months, forgot you had that, and add another ajax function, spending an hour trying to figure out what's going wrong. For something like your use case, I really doubt ajaxComplete is the right fit.

Comment: Thanks for this thought, i'm going to stay with your solution for now.